# Why does cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback fail on simple synthetic examples?

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opticalflow

`cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback` seems to work fine on natural images, but if I try it on simple synthetic examples, such as the one below, it thinks there is no flow:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=np.uint8); a[1:4] = 127; a[2] = 255; a
```

which equals

```
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)

b = np.roll(a, 1, 0); b
```

which equals

```
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

The flow:

```
flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(a, b, pyr_scale=0.5, levels=3, winsize=15, iterations=3, poly_n=5, poly_sigma=1.2, flags=0)
```

is essentially 0, as

```
np.abs(flow).max()
```

evaluates to

```
1.3305091e-13
```

I tried different `winsize` values with similar results.

Why is this happening? Are there other parameters that would work better here?

(My OpenCV version is 2.4.8. Version 3 would need `None` added as the third argument, I believe)

Comment: is `winsize = 15` appropriate for an "image" that is size `(10,10)`?  Also it seems like the algorithms behind your algorithms really don't like when motion is purely affine - it makes the matrices behind the least-squared algorithm non-invertible.  See the bottom of page 4 [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.185.585&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: @DanielF not sure about which winsize is appropriate, but `flow` is still essentially 0 with other `winsize` values (such as 2 or 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.185.585&rep=rep1&type=pdf)[1] in equations 19, 20, 23 and 25.

Notably, (sorry, hard to write equations without `mathJax` *grumble*)

```
I_x[x,y] = (A[x-1, y] - A[x+1, y]) / 2  # Equation 19
```

This reduces to `np.zeros((10,10))` in your example, which causes the follow-on problem:

```
G = sum([[I_x**2, I_x * I_y],[I_x * I_y, I_y**2]], axis = (2,3))  # Equation 23
```

Since `I_x` is zero, this means `G` takes the form

```
G = [[0, 0], [0, I_y**2]]
```

everywhere, which is a singular matrix.  Since it needs to be inverted, the solver gets stuck.

What's happening after that is difficult to follow (I can't read `c` well enough to dig into `openCV` core code), but it seems like singular matrices get skipped based on the documentation of the `minEigThreshold` parameter for [`calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk).  This may mean your output is buffer garbage, or at least some gaussian mixture of buffer garbage.

This is also why @JulioDanielReyes is able to get a response when he adds a noise parameter - this adds just enough `I_x` terms to make `G` non-singular.

Ref:

[1] Pyramidal Implementation of the Lucas Kanade Feature Tracker
Description of the algorithm, Jean-Yves Bouguet

Comment: missing parens in the first eq?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will answer your question, but besides `winsize` being too big, it is difficult for the algorithm to know which direction is moving (left/right) with such regular figure.

Try adding some noise, e.g. `a[4,4] += 1;` before the call to roll, you will see a big difference.

**Edit**: added my results

```
print(np.abs(flow).max())
```

Without noise:

```
winsize 15: 1.33051e-13
winsize 2: 6.00387e-11
```

Noise 1:

```
# a[4,4] += 1; 
winsize 15: 0.00332422
winsize 2: 1.82871
```

Noise 2:

```
# noise = np.round(np.random.random(a.shape) * 2.0).astype(np.int8)
# a = a + noise;
winsize 15: 0.207728
winsize 2: 324.527
```